# Can't download or update apps

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore

I had no problem until the few last days. My phone was full and I couldn't download anything. Then I deleted the majority of my pictures and some apps and tried to download these apps back. But the icon that pops up when it starts to download, that circle, keeps rotating forever and it doesn't download the app.

I can't also update any app, because the app badge show that I have 4 updates but when I go to the updates there are none. Any solution?